# Curve Line Graphic and Jsonfile

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, d3.js, nvd3.js

I realized this curve line graph using d3 and nvd3:

```
 d3.json('/Models/Scripts/test_data2.json', function(data) {


            nv.addGraph(function() {
                var chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart();

                // chart.transitionDuration(500);
                chart.xAxis
                    .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));
                chart.x2Axis
                    .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

                chart.yAxis
                    .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));
                chart.y2Axis
                    .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

                d3.select('#chart svg')
                    .datum(data)
                    .call(chart);

                nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

                return chart;
            });
        });
```

The question is, how should I write my json file to recognize different curves?

If I have the following json it doesn't work with two or more lines. I did several tries.

```
 [{"CurveArray":[{
      "Line1":[
          {
            "x":-52482.23046875,
            "y":0.0
          },
          {
            "x":-51380.384892578128,
            "y":0.4
          },
          {
            "x":-50278.539316406248,
            "y":2
          },
          {
            "x":-49176.693740234376,
            "y":0.9
          },
          {
            "x":-48074.848164062496,
            "y":0.7
          }
        ]},
"Line2":[
          {
            "x":-52482.23046875,
            "y":0.0
          },
          {
            "x":-51380.384892578128,
            "y":0.4
          },
          {
            "x":-50278.539316406248,
            "y":2
          },
          {
            "x":-49176.693740234376,
            "y":0.9
          },
          {
            "x":-48074.848164062496,
            "y":0.7
          }
        ]}
]}]
```

I tried to modify so:
It doesn't work again.

```
[
{
    key: "Line1",
    value: [
                {
                    "x":-52482.23046875,
                    "y":0.0
                },
                {
                    "x":-51380.384892578128,
                    "y":0.4
                },
                {
                    "x":-50278.539316406248,
                    "y":2
                },
                {
                    "x":-49176.693740234376,
                    "y":0.9
                },
                {
                    "x":-48074.848164062496,
                    "y":0.7
                }
           ]
},
{
    key: "Line2",
    value: [
                {
                    "x":-50000,
                    "y":0.0
                },
                {
                    "x":-59000,
                    "y":0.4
                },
                {
                    "x":-48000,
                    "y":2
                },
                {
                    "x":-49100,
                    "y":0.9
                },
                {
                    "x":-49800,
                    "y":0.7
                }
            ]
}
```

]

Comment: You mean like in [this example](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/lineWithFocus.html)?

Comment: You could structure your data exactly like in the example.

Comment: I don't understand. I read from a json in my example, only I should form it correctly. There is some errors when i want add a new line.

Comment: The example uses a generator function, but you can use the structure of the data it generates. In particular, it uses a list of key-value pairs where the values denote the line.

Comment: Yes exactly, but I can't plot another line, my data are okay for a Line. There are some mistakes in the json syntax and I asked here...

Comment: You haven't actually given us a non-working example.

Comment: As I've said, the example shows you the data format -- try `[ {key: "Line1", value: [{x: ...}, ...]}, {key: "Line2", value: ...}]`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff modified but it doesn't work again. You can read the code above in my original post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48389/discussion-between-sangineto-s-and-lars-kotthoff)

Comment: Apologies, this should be `values` and not `value`.

Comment: Nothing. It doesn't work

Comment: I found the error, I missed the "" in the "key" and "values" syntax. Thank you @LarsKotthoff, I really appreciated your help.